# Tell Hypervisor to Swap Allocated RAM to Paging Files

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, virtual-memory, hypervisor

Due to many running VMs in Windows 10 I am hitting my physical memory limit. Although it will be a performance hit, I want windows to allow paging of the VMs allocated memory. By default it does not do this. Any way I can hack this and make it happen?

My paging file is running on a fast M.2 drive

Comment: Have you defined the VMs with [dynamic memory](https://www.veeam.com/blog/hyper-v-dynamic-memory-managing-vm-ram.html)?

Comment: "I want windows to allow paging of the VMs allocated memory. By default it does not do this." - WHy do you believe this to be the case?  Windows by default uses a page file.  Windows within a VM would also use a page file. If the host operating system is using a page file, and you are still receiving errors about your virtual memory, your page file is likely to small on the host.  If you are receiving a out of memory exception dealing with physical memory you have to many VMs running and require more system memory (no amount of page file will solve that problem).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The VMs are using dynamic memory on most, some are fixed allocated memory. Hypervisor does not page VM allocated memory. I am hoping there is a way to page VM allocated memory in the HOST OS, to allow more VMs

Comment: Stepping back: do your VMs need as much RAM as you've assigned them? In general, best practices for VMs is that you can over provision CPU but not RAM.

Comment: Overall the system RAM is over provisioned. The VMs are started in a cascading fashion so it's not a problem. There are two ways forward to run more VMs: Assign less RAM to each VM in host OS and increase guest OS paging, or use the host OS to do it all automatically. I want to try the latter, at least to benchmark it, and see which path offers better performance. So far from my research, nobody has found a way to enable Hyper-V to use the system paging file.